# How to know which values factorization assign the text in pandas columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am using `pandas` to factorize the text values into numerical values.
I want to know what values assign by the factorization to my text values in the columns. I have attached the pictures before and after the code for the factorization.

Here is the image before the code

[image]

This is the code that I am using to factorize my DataFrame

```
def factorize_fun(df):
    obj_cols = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object].columns
    for col in obj_cols:
        df[col] = pd.factorize(df[col])[0] +1
    return df

df=factorize_fun(df)
```

Here is the image after the above code

[image]

I want some code that gives me the results in this format as i want to know during factorization what number assign to what text.

```
kindly specify your gender
1 Male
2 Female
```

Comment: You have `pd.factorize(df[col])[0]` in there - only keeping element 0. Element 1 tells you what each factor corresponds to.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. I don't want to change the  numbering. I just want to know during factorization what number assign to what text.

Comment: Dear if you know it will be kind to help me.