# Getting error accessing two dictionaries items in "for loop" in python

Tags: python

I am working on a python project in which I have 2 nested dictionaries, and I want to change the value of `dict2` dictionary with the `dict1`. However, the for loop is not able to access both dictionaries. It is taking one `dict` at a time.

How we can parse both in for loop?

```
for columnName,columnData in dict2.items(),dict1.items():
    for key in columnData:
        dict2[columnName][key]=dict1[columnName][key]
```

Error Picture:

[image: Error Picture]

`dict1`:

```
'Please select your father/guardian monthly Income from these options.': {
  'Between 25k to 50k': 1,
  'Between 75k to 100k': 1,
  'Between 50k to 75k': 1,
  'Between 100k to 150k': 1,
  'Between 150k to 200k': 1,
  'Between 200k to 250k': 1,
  "Father don't do any job": 1,
  'Between 10k to 25k': 1,
  'Between 250k to 300k': 1,
  'More than 1 million': 1,
  'Between 400k to 450k': 1,
  'Between 300k to 350k': 1,
  'Between 350k to 400k': 1,
  'Between 450k to 500k': 1,
  'Between 500k to 550k': 1,
  'Between 550k to 600k': 1,
  'Between 600k to 650k': 1,
  'Less than 10k': 1,
  'Between 750k to 800k': 1
},
```

`dict2`:

```
'Please select your father/guardian monthly Income from these options.': {6: 110,
  1: 94,
  2: 89,
  3: 75,
  4: 47,
  7: 26,
  10: 26,
  8: 22,
  5: 13,
  9: 10,
  11: 5,
  12: 4,
  17: 4,
  15: 3,
  19: 3,
  13: 2,
  14: 2,
  16: 2,
  18: 1},
```

I want the output like this

```
'Please select your father/guardian monthly Income from these options.':{
1:'Between 25k to 50k',
2:'Between 75k to 100k',
3:'Between 50k to 75k',
4:'Between 100k to 150k',
7:'Between 150k to 200k',
10:'Between 200k to 250k',
8:'Father don't do any job',
5:'Between 10k to 25k',
.....}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding an example of dict1, dict2, and a description of what you want to do.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve]. If we can have a sample of the two dictionaries we can better help you

Comment: From your output, it is not clear how to map the numbers on the left to the text on the right. For example, why is `10` mapped to `'Between 200k to 250k'`? Which information in `dict1` should be combined to `dict2` to get it?

Comment: I am trying to get the values assigned after the factorization. dict1 is before the factorization and dict2 after the factorization. Related to my query  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72636154/how-to-know-which-values-factorization-assign-the-text-in-pandas-columns-in-pyth)  i was just trying solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for key1, key2 in zip(dict1.keys(), dict2.keys()):
    for sub_key1, sub_key2 in zip(dict1[key1].keys(), dict2[key2].keys()):
        dict2[key2][sub_key2] = sub_key1
```

Comment: And how we can sort the dict after this ?

Comment: {6: 'Between 25k to 50k', 1: 'Between 75k to 100k', 2: 'Between 50k to 75k', 3: 'Between 100k to 150k', 4: 'Between 150k to 200k', 7: 'Between 200k to 250k', 10: "Father don't do any job",.........}

Answer (score -1):

You could either add the two lists together and loop through that, or have another loop on the outside like this
for dict in [dict1.keys(),dict2.keys()]:

Comment: Then how to access dict1 and dict2 in inside loop?

Comment: Well, which one did you decide to use? I gave ypu two options

Comment: Please if you write the code for both.

Comment: Sure can you include the dictionary and what your trying to do?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).